# How to input multiple values from same input field in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, input, push

This is my code

```
const Diagnosis = () => {

  const medicine =[]
  var [inputs , setInputs] = useState()
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputs(event.target.value)
    
  };
  const handleAdd = () => {
    medicine.push(inputs)
  };
}
return (
    <div className='container'>
    <div>
    <h1 className='heading'>DIAGNOSIS</h1>
      <form>
          <label className='label'>
            Medicine :<br/>
            <input className='input' name='medicine' type='text' placeholder='One medicine at a time' onChange={handleChange}  value={inputs}/>
            </label><br/>
            </form>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleAdd}>Add medicine</Button>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The way it's supposed to work is , user enter value in the input field and onclick that input gets pushed into medicine array
But for some reason , once the user changes the input field , the medicine array becomes empty

I can't figure what i am doing wrong in here and is there any better way to store multiple inputted from the same input field in an array

I've tried everything i could think of but in no matter what , whenever there is any change in input field , medicine array becomes empty suddenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const medicine =[]
```

This local variable will be re-created every time the component renders, so it's always replaced by an empty array. If you want the array to persist between renders it should be a state:

```
const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState([]);
// ...
const handleAdd = () => {
  setMedicine(prev => {
    return [...prev, inputs];
  })
};
```